# How do I check if a Camel message body is stream based?

Tags: apache-camel

The `Message.getBody()` method javadoc says,

> Notice if the message body is stream based then....

So how do I check if the body is stream based? The check like this

```
Object body = exchange.getIn().getBody();
if (body instanceof InputStream) {
```

doesn't work for, say, files. I am writing a generic code and it should do certain things for incoming streams, and leave non-streaming objects intact, thus I am cautious to call

```
Object body = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class);
```

because I don't know what it will do with plain String or List or Integer etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple single check that covers 100% situations. Camel is open ended in terms of what payload format it supports and hence the message body is just a `java.lang.Object`. So to check if its streaming based, you need to check for streaming types such as `java.io.InputStream', but then you also have other types like files, and from 3rd party components that may have their own representation of streaming data.

Camel has built in stream caching (https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/stream-caching.html) where it supports most streaming types and if you use that, then you can check if the body is an `org.apache.camel.StreamCache` instance.

Comment: Thank you, can you consider to introduce some umbrella interface for all stream based message types.  ..?